# ajax in javascript not working. not reading the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a simple JS script to load ajax functions.... and it doesn't work... I debugged using document.write to see where the problem lied and I can see my TEST 1 but not my TEST 2...

MY HTML

```
<html>
<title>Ajax Infinite scroll using jQuery - InfoTuts</title>
<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>


<img id='loading' src='img/loading.gif'>
<div class="masonry" >
    <div id="demoajax" cellspacing="0"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

MY JavaScript

```
 var ajax_arry=[];
 var ajax_index =0;
 var sctp = 100;
 $(function()
{
   $('#loading').show();
/*  document.write("TEST1");  */

$.ajax(
{

/*  document.write("TEST2");  */
    url:"scroll.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response)
        {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#demoajax').html(response); 
        }

   });

 /*  MORE CODE BELOW  */
```

my document.write  TEST 1 prints on screen, but my TEST 2 can't print..

It seems it's not going in the $ajax( section of the code

Comment: TEST 2 can't print because it's in the middle of an object declaration. Get rid of it and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Your second document .write is not working due to stricture. the thing you pass to ajax function should be an json object .

Comment: it's not working, I get a error 500 Internal Server error in the console... what is that exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use document.write to debug. Browsers have a console. Use console.log and you can set break points.

And you are creating an error putting document.write in the middle of an object!!! That is a syntax error.

If you are trying to figure out why the Ajax call is not loading, add an error handler and see if it is getting called.

```
$('#loading').show();
console.log("loading shown");

$.ajax({
  url: "scroll.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: "actionfunction=showData&page=1",
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("success", response);
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#demoajax').html(response);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("error", arguments);
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that.... It is not being called and in my console, I see an error 500 Internal server error :
`POST http://...scroll.php 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery.min.js:4 sendjquery.min.js:4 m.extend.ajaxscript.js:8 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 jjquery.min.js:2 k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 J`  any ideas what I should be doing now ?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to close your function;

put this   }); after your ajax call.

if you got "500 (Internal Server Error)", you may have to change the Permissions of that PHP file.

Comment: the closing tag was present in the code below... and I tried putting CHMOD to 777 and still I get the 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Do you have any other working Ajax calls(to PHP file) in your project???  Else, try to install these,                             *** yum install php-xml
*** yum install php-xmlrpc

Answer (score -1):

try by putting document.write("TEST2"); inside success function.

Answer (score -1):

Put `$.ajax` on document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    /*  document.write("TEST2");  */
    url:"scroll.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#demoajax').html(response); 
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: no changes.. .I see an error 500 Internal server error : `POST http://...scroll.php 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery.min.js:4 sendjquery.min.js:4 m.extend.ajaxscript.js:8 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 jjquery.min.js:2 k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 J` any ideas what I should be doing now ?